# Facebook link on mobile should open the facebook app and not the browser

Tags: html, facebook

On the mobile version of the website I created

I tried to link to the Facebook app with the following code
`fb://page/[pageID]`

It works perfectly on iOS, but on Android it will work with the following code
`fb://profile/[pageID]`

Does anyone know a solution? Maybe some JavaScript to detect the device and then change the URL for that device.

Comment: Please post your code and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing this, maybee someone else can use it,

the classes `hideonmobile` & `hideonbigscreen` are `display:none` in the right media query

```
<div class="hideonmobile"><a href="http://www.facebook.nl/[facebook page]" target="blank"></a></div> <div class="hideonbigscreen"><a href="fb://profile/[facebook ID]" onclick="window.open('fb://page/[facebook ID]'); return true;"></a></div>
```